# Release build changes behavior when run outside of the debugger

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, debugging

I'm making a program with C++ and Lua. When I run the program in Release mode OUTSIDE of the debugger, the program doesn't behave as expected (it doesn't crash, it just doesn't do what I thought it would). When I start it from the debugger, it behaves just fine.

I understand that there are differences in the way a program will be run in a debugger vs outside of one (Heap differences? Some uninitialized variables?). Is it possible to configure the debugger so it will run the Release version of my program with as few changes as possible, so I can try to make this problem happen while debugging?

Comment: It sounds like you may have some code that produces Undefined Behaviour.  But hard to tell without seeing code.  Can you post the troublesome code?

Comment: Not really. I don't know what the problem is exactly. Several entities in my program aren't displaying, but I have yet to narrow down why.

Comment: Are you sure that you are running the exact same build inside the debugger and outside of it?

Comment: You can just run with the debugger in release mode. If you change the project settings to produce debug symbols in release mode as well, it will be rather similar to the debug mode.

Comment: @lezebulon Yeah, I even cleaned and rebuilt, and verified that the same EXE is being run in both cases.

Comment: @Bo Right, I've been doing that, but the problem is that doing so changes the behavior of the program. I'm reasonably suspicious that the problem is an uninitialized variable somewhere, so I can just do it the "hard" way and take a pass through my code. But it would be great to be able to use the debugger to see what's going on without the debugger changing things on me.

Comment: Or you can simply attach the debugger to the exe...

Comment: @lezebulon Do you happen to know if there's a way to do that so that it attaches right as the program starts? This problem occurs right when the program starts up.

Comment: I don't know if there is a proper way, but I'm sure that if you put something like sleep(100000); it should work for you?

Comment: @lezebulon Thank you- I did exactly that and was able to successfully debug the problem. As I suspected- uninitialized variable!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a couple of things to try:

- Run outside the debugger but then attach to the process afterwards.  When the process is started from the debugger it will have a slightly different environment, so if that is the cause of the different behaviour then this will allow you to debug it
- Create a release build with optimisation turned off and see if you get the same behaviour running inside and outside of the debugger. If you can still reproduce the issue then this will make debugging it (by using the above Attach Process method) a lot easier

Comment: Thank you- attaching to the program after it was already running allowed me to debug this problem. I didn't need to try the second suggestion but it was also a very good one!

Comment: Out of interest, what was the problem? I'm interested to know how the environment differs (aside from the debug heap) when running outside the debugger.

Comment: It was an uninitialized variable! Simple problem in the end. A member boolean (for a class that was created from the heap) that I somehow never initialized was always starting as true when ran in the debugger, and ended up being false outside of the debugger.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure about making the debugger act like a release build but you can simulate them somewhat.

Depends on what exactly the differences in behaviour are.

Are all the variables initialised?  The debugger does that.  You can also use asm { int 3 } to break in release mode.