# Release bugs only show up when running EXE outside of Visual Studio

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010

I have an issue that I am trying to debug that only happens when I run the release exe built directly outside of Visual Studio. When I am executing it from within Visual Studio the program behaves normally, even when using specific project properties to debug a "release" build, such as turning on optimizations, explained on the following page.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fsk896zz%28v=vs.100%29.aspx

I experience no issues using those settings and running/debugging from withing VS, but when I copy the exe and required files (images and some dll) to it's own directory and run the exe directly instead of through VS2010 I experience a couple errors. This is making it hard to debug as I can't get the issue to occur inside VS no matter what settings I use.

Am I missing some settings or is there still more things that happen differently outside of VS2010 that I can't simulate from within VS 2010?

I am not using any arguments or environment variables that could be affecting it and the file structure from the working directory is identical to the way it is in the source code directory.

Edit:
Found the bug (uninitialized variable) by attaching to the exe using the information here:
[Release build changes behavior when run outside of the debugger](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11146301/release-build-changes-behavior-when-run-outside-of-the-debugger)

Comment: The "couple of errors" you elude to could be quite-telling. Perhaps include those.

Comment: Put `__debugbreak();` in your main() function.

Comment: Just to confirm: Your regular release build turns on all optimizations, correct? (By trying to debug a release build, you generally add debug symbols and lower compiler optimization)
What kind of errors do you see? Fatal ones?

Comment: @Raja My Release build has References and Enable COMDAT folding set to yes. Not sure what else there is. I'm just getting some errors like an image is staying on the screen when it should have been destroyed. And nothing is actually crashing or anything.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Visual C++'s debugger can attach to already running processes.  (Debug -> Attach to Process.)  You could try using that to start your exe outside of Visual Studio then attach to it and debug the error.  As another way of doing this, as @Hans Passant suggested, you can also add `__debugbreak();` to your process to force Windows to offer a Debug prompt when you run it and attach the Visual Studio debugger that way.

I'd be tempted to use [Process Monitor](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896645.aspx) to compare the executions of the exe inside and outside of the debugger to see if they're really doing the same thing with regards to file access, DLL loading, etc.

See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/11146301/25507) for a similar issue.

Comment: The reason was a variable that was uninitialized. I found it due to your solution of attaching to the process. Strange how variables will be initialized when run from inside VS, even if you have optimizations turned on. I forgot I could attach to the process to debug. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Two thoughts spring immediately to mind:
- uninitialized variable
- race condition. Take a look at your threading model, and consider locking critical sections or variable accesses.